# Download prompt shows up when trying to download file using selenium webdriver with latest chrome driver 117 in incognito mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to download a file using selenium webdriver. I have set the download directory and other parameters as well. The same code was working with chrome driver version 116. Since the browser version was updated to 117 the code is now failing as the download prompt shows up. However when I disable the incognito mode the file gets downloaded to the set download directory path. I am using selenium version 3.141.59.

Sample code

package com.test;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TestDownload
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driver\\117\\chromedriver.exe");
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", "D:\\driver");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        //working fine when the below line is commented
        options.addArguments("incognito");
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",prefs);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.linkText("4.12.1 (September 4, 2023)"));
        e.click();
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem on Selenium 3.141.59 and on the newest one 4.12.1.
Chrome version is 117.0.5938.63.
Tried it with chromedrivers 117.0.5938.62 and 117.0.5938.88.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable two Chromium experimental features: **download-bubble** and **download-bubble-v2**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TestDownload
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driver\\117\\chromedriver.exe");
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", "D:\\driver");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        //working fine when the below line is commented
        options.addArguments("incognito");
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",prefs);

        Map<String, Object> localState = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> experiments = new ArrayList<>();
        experiments.add("download-bubble@2");
        experiments.add("download-bubble-v2@2");
        localState.put("browser.enabled_labs_experiments", experiments);
        options.setExperimentalOption("localState", localState);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.linkText("4.12.1 (September 4, 2023)"));
        e.click();
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

I'm using Chrome 117.0.5938.132 and Selenium 4.8.0 and this solution worked for me.
You can pause your program in debugger and open chrome://flags/ to make sure the options are disabled:
[chrome flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nXZA.png)

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you! I've been looking everywhere for a solution for this.

Comment: Works on Chrome 117.0.5938.63 and Selenium 4.12.1. Thank you :]

Comment: UPDATE: Does not work on Chrome 119.0.6045.106. Those "bubble" flags are not available anymore. System download prompt shows up even though "chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);".

Answer (score 1):

For driver119 worked with below code in Java

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Chrome 119.0.6045.106 and Selenium 4.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TestDownload
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driver\\117\\chromedriver.exe");
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", "D:\\driver");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        options.addArguments("incognito");
        //solution added on next line
        prefs.put("localState", "browser.enabled_labs_experiments": ["download-bubble@2", "download-bubble-v2@2"]);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",prefs);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.linkText("4.12.1 (September 4, 2023)"));
        e.click();
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please comment below line and try? looks like its happening only in Incognito mode. This workaround fixed my issue.

options.addArguments("incognito");

Comment: Have already mentioned that it works when incognito mode is disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Added below line for C# Selenium and issue is fixed

```
options.AddLocalStatePreference("browser", new { enabled_labs_experiments = new string[] { "download-bubble@2", "download-bubble-v2@2" } });
```