# How to avoid destination path selection dialog on download?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, download

In Python with Google Chrome I'm accessing a website then downloading a file. It must be saved to folder configured in Selenium options. It worked however, now a window opens to choose path to save file to instead of downloading it to configured folder directly.

The settings:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'download.default_directory': path_download,
    'download.directory_upgrade': True,
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2,
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1
})
```

Python 3.11.1. Selenium 4.12.0. webdriver-manger 4.0.0. Chrome 117.0.5938.92. I want to download to configured folder without destination path selection dialog popup.

Answer (score 0):

doing more research I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77125660/download-prompt-shows-up-when-trying-to-download-file-using-selenium-webdriver-w) that explained how to get around this problem, to do this, we just need to remove the anonymous mode from the automation.