# How to bypass system file explorer (file save location) when downloading a file using selenium with Incognito mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download a file using selenium and able by pass file explorer (save location for file) in chrome with below code.

Chrome Browser : 119.0.6045.159
Chrome Driver : chromedriver 119

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

String downloadDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads";
        
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
        
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false")    
//chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", Boolean.FALSE)
//chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "False");

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But however the same will not work if i open browser with Incognito

`options.addArguments("--incognito");`

Tried adding different arguments and prefs, nothing helped. Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Thanks!

Tried opening a Incognito browser and download file. Where im getting file explorer.

Expectation is that file should auto download as the path defined and prompt disabled

Tried like this also, it didn't work
[Download prompt shows up when trying to download file using selenium webdriver with latest chrome driver 117 in incognito mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77125660/download-prompt-shows-up-when-trying-to-download-file-using-selenium-webdriver-w)

Answer (score 0):

Worked with this finally

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this solution will stop working after updating to Chrome 121.